# MongoDB pipeline group and take all data from one column and make the average

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, pipeline, group

[image]i have a dataset with some columns like countries, players, kd_ratio

i want to write a pipeline where i can group kd_ratio from all the countries and get the average.

Im trying this:

```
db.CSGO.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: { country: { $country: "$all" }, nick: { $nick: "$all" } },
        averageQuantity: { $avg: "$kd_ratio" },
        
    }}])
```

Comment: What is `$country`, `$nick`, and `"$all"`?

Comment: i added a picture of the dataset

Comment: In `"$group"`, if you use `"_id": "$country"`, then `averageQuantity: { $avg: "$kd_ratio" }`, then this  should provide the average `"kd_ratio"` for each `"country"` in the collection.  If this isn't what you are looking for, would you provide some desired sample output docs?  Also, please don't use images for code/errors/backtraces/etc. - just paste the text into a codeblock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what rickhg12hs the code will be this:

```
db.CSGO.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id:  '$country' ,
            averageQuantity: { $avg: "$kd_ratio" },
        
        }}])
```